# Npqsql.PoolManager threw an exception

Tags: c#, .net, npgsql

the following code threw an exception with the text

> The type initializer for 'Npgsql.PoolManager' threw an exception.

```
var db = new NpgsqlConnection(Host=....;Port=...;Username=...;Password=...;Database=...;Command Timeout=3600)
db.Open();
```

.NET 4.6.1

Npgsql 4.0.30319

On my computer with VS 2010 installed the app is working. But on an other WIN10 machine I get the error.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the full exception type, message and stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Stack - Trace

> - Npgsql.PoolManager.TryGetValue(String key, ConnectorPool &pool)
> - Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.GetPoolAndSettings()
> - ... my app